# Random data in array without repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, random

I have a problem with this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/markusfenix/tk6mdqsn/)
i just want to know if there is a way in that the array isn't repeated at the end of the loop.

HTML:

```
<div id="words" class="word"></div>  
<button>word</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var data = {"seed": [
            {
                "num1":"title1",
                "num2":"title2",
                "num3": [ "1","2","3" ]
            },
            {
                "num1":"title3",
                "num2":"title4",
                "num3": [ "a","b","c" ]
            },
            {
                "num1":"title5",
                "num2":"title6",
                "num3": [ "d","gh","34" ]
            }
    ]};
    var conta = data.seed.length;
    var recorre = data.seed;
    //alert(conta);

    function getNumbers() {
        var jokeId = Math.floor((Math.random()*conta));
        var joke = $('.word');
        var result = data.seed[jokeId].num3;
        var categ = data.seed[jokeId].num1;
        joke.empty()
        for (var c in result) {
            var newElement = document.createElement('div');
            newElement.id = result[c];  
            newElement.innerHTML = result[c]; 
            joke.append(newElement);
        }
    }

    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        getNumbers();
    });
});
```

Comment: lookup "Fisher-Yates Shuffle'

Comment: what do you mean by *array isn't repeated at the end of the loop*?

Comment: @MitchWheat is correct, but there's more than one way to use the principals of Fisher-Yates shuffling. I gave two options in my answer with some thought around proactive shuffling vs lazy shuffling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### One option: Shuffle first

@MitchWheat gives a good clue in the comments above. Shuffling your data in advance is one option:

1. Shuffle `data` using a Fisher-Yates shuffle.
2. Every button click, just iterate through `data` and display the next one.
3. When you hit the end, reshuffle.

FWIW: The Fisher-Yates shuffle is very easy to implement... it's something like:

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
  var i, j, a, b;
  for(i = arr.length - 1; i <= 1; i--) {
     j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
     a = arr[i];
     b = arr[j];
     arr[i] = b;
     arr[j] = a;
  }
}
```

#### Second option: Lazy Shuffle

Just `splice()` out the ones you've already used:

1. Copy `data` into another array `copy`.
2. On click:

   1. Pick a random index of `copy`.
   2. get it with `var item = copy.splice(randomIndex, 1)`
   3. display item
   4. when you hit the end, copy `data` into `copy` again.

In reality, you're *sort of* doing a Fisher-Yates shuffle here in a lazy way. Because you're starting with the full array, and picking a random value and pulling it out (rather than swapping it), then reducing the size by 1, rather than decrementing `i`.